# Ruby hash syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, haml

I'm new to ruby and trying to get used to the new syntax.
This is a line of code from the project i'm in, it's a simple description on the footer
that shows the local company number, but the syntax of the second line is a little confusing to me.

```
%dt Indonesia
  %dd{ itemprop: 'telephone' }= I18n.with_locale(:id) { t('meta.phone_number') }
```

so  {itemprop: 'telephone'} is just a block that maps a symbol itemprop to the value 'telephone', but then why do you have "=" in between the I18n.with_locale(:id)? what does it do?
Also, is the third block {t('meta.phone_number')} a parameter for the I18n.with_locale(:id)?
or is I18n.with_locale(:id) even a method call?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Half of this is HAML syntax, not ruby/hash syntax.

Comment: Actually, why don't you read through [HAML docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html)? It will answer most of these questions.

Comment: The %dd tag is used to describe a term/name in a description list

Comment: http://haml.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

- `%dd`: tell **Haml** to emit a `<dd>` tag.
- `{ itemprop: 'telephone' }`: tell **Haml** that the current tag should have an attribute `itemprop` with value `telephone`.
- `=`: tell **Haml** to set the text content of the current tag to whatever **Ruby** says the rest of the line evaluates to.
- `I18n.with_locale(:id) { ... }`: tell **Ruby** to invoke the method `with_locale` on `I18n`, with one parameter (the symbol `:id`) and a block.
- `t('meta.phone_number')`: tell **Ruby** to invoke the `t` helper method, with one parameter (string `meta.phone_number`).

All in all, it should generate something like this:

```
<dd itemprop="telephone">電話番号</dd>
```

if 電話番号 was a translation registered for `meta.phone_number` and the current locale was Japanese.